# Emulate Android Phone on Android Tablet

Tags: android, debugging, tablet, simulator

I wonder if there is some kind of tool to emulate Android handys on an android tablet. I would like to use it for developing games for android platforms and to check size and resolution issues.

Of course there are different simulators running on PC, but it would be helpful to simulate the behaviour on the nexus tablet.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can to this on some devices. It's especially useful on the Nexus 10 because it has a large screen and a really high density. You can use ADB to force it to emulate other resolutions and display densities. It's perfect for testing alternate layout and drawable resources.

For instance, you could force it to behave similar to a G1 by doing this:

```
adb shell am display-size 640x480
adb shell am display-density 160
```

Make sure the screen is turned off when sending these commands and clear them by replacing the size/density with "reset"

```
adb shell am display-size reset
adb shell am display-density reset
```

https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible.  It would take lots better hardware than a Nexus 7/10 to do emulation.